# Is there a way to reduce precision in pandas date_range column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe and one of the column has DateTime column.
I am only interested in date time values until the seconds. So for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.rand(5), 
             'b': pd.date_range(start=datetime.now(), periods=5, freq='999ms')})

    a                      b
0   0.884220    2019-12-12 23:08:54.275763
1   0.904123    2019-12-12 23:08:54.775763
2   0.314661    2019-12-12 23:08:55.275763
3   0.282793    2019-12-12 23:08:55.775763
4   0.112378    2019-12-12 23:08:56.275763
```

I want to create another dataframe whose time precision is only until seconds

```
    a   b
0   0.884220    2019-12-12 23:08:54
1   0.904123    2019-12-12 23:08:54
2   0.314661    2019-12-12 23:08:55
3   0.282793    2019-12-12 23:08:55
4   0.112378    2019-12-12 23:08:56
```

Can you please suggest how to achieve this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `round` method.

```py
new_df = df.copy()
new_df['b'] = new_df['b'].dt.round("1s")
```

If it was in the index:

```py
df.index.round("1s")
```

If you want to change the DataFrame in place:

```py
df.index = df.index.round("1s")
```

else:

```py
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.index = new_df.index.round("1s")
```

As a side note, depending on the expected behavior also `ceil` and `floor` are available.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio. 'round' works only if the datetime is an Index and not one of the columns. I can make do with it. But if I drop the index, the precision reappears. So it is not truncating entirely, it is just hiding the precision.

Comment: if it's a column, you should use `dt` to access the datetime properties. e.g. `df['column_name'].dt.round("1s")`. Note that this doesn't change in-place, so you'll have to re-assign it `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].dt.round("1s")`.

Comment: @PrashanthSuresh I edited the answer, it should do what you asked for now

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.strftime` on column `b` to get the format you want

```
df['b']=pd.to_datetime(df.b.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

You use just `df['b']=df.b.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` but the column will of type `object` and not `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Thanks moys. This worked perfectly. And the column type remained as datetime64[ns]

Comment: If the answer helped, consider upvoting & accepting it.

Comment: I don't like making a negative comment, but this is really, really inefficient. `round` is designed exactly for this purpose, doing a round-trip conversion to string is a hack. As a side note, if you have any timezone-related information, it will be lost.

Comment: @GiorgioBalestrieri You are correct, it seems that my solution is inneficient (take twice as much time as your). I was not aware of `dt.round` hence I put the answer that i did. I have up-voted your answer now :-)